# Table with triggers on INSERTs not LOCKing to make INSERTS

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to INSERT some data to a table `test`. This table has triggers set on it to replicate the data to other databases.

However, when I INSERT the data, it throws the error 
`ERROR 1100 (HY000) at line 3 in file: 'test_insert.sql': Table 'test' was not locked with LOCK TABLES.` even though I have LOCKED the table and have the correct privileges to LOCK it.
Here's the `test_insert.sql` file

```
LOCK TABLES `test` WRITE;

INSERT INTO `test` ('a','b')
VALUES
    (1,2),
    .
    .
    .   

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Is there some other method to LOCK tables with triggers set on them?

Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_insert AFTER INSERT ON #{db_name}.test FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO #{other_db}.test (select * from #{db_name}.test where #{primary_index} = NEW.#{primary_index});
```

Comment: Are you saying the published code is within a trigger? If it's not then I cannot reproduce your error and would need to see the triggers.

Comment: No the published code is outside the trigger, but for the same table `test` there is a trigger set on INSERT statement. I'll add the trigger @P.Salmon

Comment: Not with you - you cannot action a table which called the trigger in the trigger - you can manipulate new.values in some triggers.

Comment: I've added the trigger @P.Salmon

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Stored Objects  /  Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html)

> **SQL Statements Not Permitted in Stored Routines**
>
> Stored routines cannot contain arbitrary SQL statements. The following statements are not permitted:
>
> - The locking statements LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES.
> - ...

Answer (score 0):

This statement select * from #{db_name}.test where #{primary_index} = NEW.#{primary_index}

doesn't make a lot of sense - why would you do this when you already processing each row of the insert

`INSERT INTO #{other_db}.test values (new.col1,new.col2...);` looks more appropriate.